# Override sklearn fit() method to add additional functionality

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a class that implements the fit() method from sklearn (a Pipeline) and I want to add additional functionality to its fit() method, but to keep the original as well. For starters, it would be enough to just add a print statement. **I want the fit() method to do exactly what it is doing naturally, but also print my statement**. This is my non-working code:

```
class MyPipeline(sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline):
    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params): # arguments from original fit
        print('Print statement')
        return super().fit(X=X, **fit_params)
```

I have been researching for some while but I'm unsure where to go from here, as it does not work. The error message I get is

```
ValueError: Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), got None
```

But it's hard to duplicate since it's a package with thousands of lines of code. I don't think this error message is necessarily related to what I'm trying to do. I am just particularly interested in the high-level knowledge of how to override a method when keeping the functionality and add new one. Hopefully that is if there's a general way, or if it depends on every particular method.

Comment: What kind of steps do you have in your pipeline? It seems like you need `y` parameter for caling `.fit()` method.

Comment: @BenjaminRio yes, that is exactly what was needed. It works after that. For some reason I assumed my usage of super() was inherently flawed and did not consider such a simple issue. Assumed that y was somehow passed naturally. Thanks.